# Facebook Canvas Application: FB.AppEvents is undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas

I am trying to set up events for my Canvas (facebook) application. I am sure I initialize the FB object correctly, because the app works entirely besides logging events but here it is.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: FB_APPID,
        status: true,
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: false,
        oauth: true
    });
}


(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The issue is that the FB object I have does not have a .AppEvents attribute or method or anything. I did a console log on the object and there is not a AppEvents portion.

No matter where I try and call it, FB.AppEvents.logEvent('message'); just causes the error: TypeError: FB.AppEvents is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?
Why does the FB object not actually have a .AppEvents method/attribute?

Any help would be appriciated! thank you

Comment: Where did you read about AppEvents existing on FB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting, I hadn’t noticed that feature myself yet, seems to be pretty new.

Looks like you are using the “old” JS SDK there,

```
//connect.facebook.net/{locale}/all.js
```

The new one uses the address

```
//connect.facebook.net/{locale}/sdk.js
```

– try with that, and see if the object is available then.

(I think the new one requires the API version to use to be specified explicitly as well, so make sure to update your `FB.init` parameters as well – for details, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2)